# How to implement Authorization in asp.net Webforms with different access rights with different user roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to implement authorization in my ASP.Net Webform application, here in my application there are diff users like Super, Admin and Normal users. super user is having access of all the menus but the rest of the users having less access compared to super user. super user will provide the menu access to Admin & normal user. menu access is diff from user to user (Admin/Normal).

Example :

```
Admin-1  Admin-2   NormalUser-1  NormalUser-2

menu1    menu2     menu1         menu3
menu2    menu3     menu3         --
```

any idea, please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by several ways.

1. You can do it using asp.net [membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. You can built your custom logic by creating roles, groups, users using DB tables and implement custom logic for the same using business layer of your application.

Once you build this api , showing menu will be based on this.

Comment: already the application was developed by hiding/showing menus based on user access, but i want to restrict the user to enter in any unauthorized page. In my case there are more than 100 menus & i want to implement based on user access not on role basis.

Comment: You need to design things before implementation.

Comment: could you please explain, how we can design.

Comment: Direction is already provided in the above answer. First build administative features such as role,permission. and attach these permission while creating user through built administrative functionality. By this you can add as many users with different permission sets as you want.

Comment: If you have built in functionality then you need base page for all the pages and in the base page check if user is authorised for requested page. Hope this helps.